# Why is type cast necessary when variable is already defining the type?

Tags: objective-c, casting

I have a custom UIViewController that I use as a popover's content view controller.  This custom UIViewController is defined like this...

```
@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController <MyCustomDelegate>
```

I then have a method in another class where I refer to the popover's contentViewController like so...

```
-(void)someMethod:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController

    UIViewController<MuCustomDelegate> *theCustomViewController;
```

So since I've already defined what `theCustomViewController` is, why do I have to do this on the next line after that...

```
theCustomViewController = (UIViewController<MyCustomDelegate>*)myUIPopOverController.contentViewController;
```

Why doesn't the compiler / XCode Editor, or whatever, already know what the delegate is instead of making me cast it after I've already defined it

Thanks

Comment: Show us the definition of `someThing.myDelegate`

Comment: @Almo - just updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your update, you are asking about the need to cast `myUIPopOverController.contentViewController`.

Simple - the `contentViewController` property has a type of `UIViewController *`. You can't assign that directly to a variable of type `UIViewController<MuCustomDelegate> *`.

The addition of the protocol means you need a specific type of `UIViewController`. The compiler can't just assume that `contentViewController` happens to be such a value. So you use the cast to tell the compiler, "trust me, I know what it really is".

Comment: You're correct, my original post was wrong, I updated it to refect your comment, but it still requires that I cast it as indicated in the post.

Comment: Ok, but so much of Obj-C is dynamic... you call something an id for instance, and send whatever to it.  I'm fairly new to Obj-C, but it just seemed that this shouldn't be necessary to tell the compiler to cast it when I've already defined what 'it' is.  Doesn't seem as dynamic as I would have expected of the language. ???  Oh well.

Comment: But you haven't defined what `contentViewController` is. Apple did when they created the `UIPopoverController` class. They declared that `contentViewController` has a type of `UIViewController`. So at compile time (not runtime) the compiler only know that you want to assign a value of type `UIViewController *` to a variable of type `UIViewController<MyCustomDelegate> *`. They are not the same. You need the cast to make the compiler happy. What happens at runtime is a whole other situation.

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern is:

```
// in MyClass.h
@protocol MyClassDelegate;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property(weak,nonatomic) id<MyClassDelegate>delegate;
@end

@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (NSInteger)myClassNeedsAnInt:(MyClass *)instanceOfMyClass;
@end
```

With that done, then in MyClass.m it should be easy to say, without any further casting:

```
NSInteger anInt = [self.delegate myClassNeedsAnInt:self];
```

A customer of this class says:

```
// in MyCustomerClass.h or in a private interface in .m
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyCustomerClass : NSObject <MyClassDelegate>
@end
```

And in its implementation, set itself as the delegate and implement the delegate protocol:

```
MyClass *myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClassInstance.delegate = self;

- (NSInteger)myClassNeedsAnInt:(MyClass *)instanceOfMyClass {
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question of why the cast is needed in the code in question.

Comment: It was a better answer before the edit.  To the extent the OP's use differs from the canon, he/she would see the warning.  That difference became clearer after the edit.